# Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) when resetting password for some users

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, active-directory-group

I'm getting above error when trying to reset password of some users. 
**This error does not happen for all users but only for some users.**

Code snippet

```
        PrincipalContext principalContext = null;
        try {
            principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainName, ServiceAC, ServicePWD);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            **code omitted**
        }

        UserPrincipal usr = null;

        try{
           
            usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, user.userName);

        } catch(Exception e){
            **code omitted**
        }

    

        //user is available in active directory change password
        var newPassword = requestedPassword;
        usr.SetPassword(newPassword); // **This line throws error**

        usr.Enabled = true;


        try {
            usr.Save();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            **code omitted**
        }
```

When setPassword is called, it throws and error below.

Stack Trace

````
  Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
  at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.SetPassword(DirectoryEntry de, String 
  newPassword)
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.SetPassword(AuthenticablePrincipal 
  p, String newPassword)
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PasswordInfo.SetPassword(String newPassword)
  at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthenticablePrincipal.SetPassword(String 
  newPassword)```
````

Comment: Seems like the context your code is connecting as does not have rights to 'set passwords' for some users. Check and see if these users have higher privileged role(s), or built in roles - such as 'domain admin' for example.

Comment: Check if your Application has higher permissions as compared to that of Users in AD, so that the application can change the password for those users.